# Disable parent button from child iframe javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is there a way to disable button from inner iframe javascript file to parent html file. for example:

```html
<body>
   <iframe src="frame1.html" name="frame1" height="100%"></iframe>
   <div id="test1"></div>
   <button type="button" id="myBtn">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Basically, frame1.html has its own frame1.js file and from this file i would like to disable the button "myBtn". by the way, both parent and child urls are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reference to your parent HTML scope by using the "window.parent" method. Here is more information about "window.parent" and "window.top" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent .

And vice versa you can access your iframe score from the parent by `document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow` where *targetFrame* is your iframe id.

In your case you can use:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
```